# moving from fragment to bottomNavitem, Onclick of that bottomNavitem, it opens that fragment again i need to open start fragment again,without delay?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

i tried to open bottomNavitem from fragment with this code on ,it opens bottomnavitem ,on comming back same bottomnavitem it open same fragement while i need to open starting fragment ,using popbackstack removes but it shoes delay bad ui

```
         AppPreference.lastSelectedCoinName = it.replace("/", "")
         //       findNavController().popBackStack()
                (activity as HomeActivity).changeBottomNavItem(2)
```

Comment: This piece of code isn't enough, provide your full code.

Comment: above code selects bottomnavigationitem 2 ,this inside click listenr

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Android Navigation i think it would solve your issue